# Facing trouble to parse json response using python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

Running my script I get an error - "string indices must be integers". As I'm new to parse json data, I can't figure out the mistakes I'm making. Here is the code I have tried with:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.redmart.com/v1.5.8/catalog/search?')
res = r.json()
for item in res:
    print(item['category_tags'][0]['title'])
```

I've edited my code putting an url in it to make the status clear.

Comment: Print the value of res; your code assumes `res` is a list of dicts.  I bet it's not.  If viewing that doesn't fix your problem, then include the first part of that print statement in your question.

Comment: More specifically, what is `item`?  A dictionary or a list/

Comment: Thanks sir hpaulj, for the clarity. It's dictionary.

Comment: `item` is a dictionary *key*, not a dictionary. You'll need to do `res[item] ... ` instead

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I've got it sorted. Here is the working code:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.redmart.com/v1.5.8/catalog/search?')
js = r.json()
items = js['products']
for item in items:
    print(item['title'], item['sku'])
```